# Why multilevel routing in express doesn't work properly?

Tags: node.js, express, router

I'm trying to make a simple routing in node.js with express. Long story short:

```
app.use('/valut-servis', valut_servis);         //This works    
app.use('/valut/servis', valut_servis);         //This doesn't
```

I expected these to act in a same way. They do lead to same script, but in that script, when I use *res.sendFile(__dirname + '/whatever.html');* to serve an html file, all the relative paths in that file stop working, because it made itself new root named "valut" inside of it's original root folder.

I'm doing something ridiculously wrong, please help.

Comment: Those two are completely different routes. The endpoints won't give thesame result unless they are made to do so. Please provide enough information so that we can help. More source code is needed.

Comment: @TeddyMcZieuwa They are made to do so, they both run the `valut_servis` function. Except when the OP checks for the path inside that function, which I think you can assume he doesn't, the actual result returned by express will be the exact same.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected, but I see how that is inconvenient here. You relative links indeed do not work when you add another `/` into the url of the base file.

You can

1. Use a `<base href="/valut-servis">` tag to make your paths resolve like absolute paths
2. change all the paths in your file to be absolute (similar to 1, actually)
3. if it is just assets, have those assets also be served from the subdirectory (with something like `app.use('/valut', express.static('/your_assets_folder'))`)

Let me know if any of those make it work for you, and which one you ended up choosing :)